# Should I cast a close vote for an almost ignored question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have posted this question on Stack Overflow a few months ago, but it has attracted almost no attention, and no comment or response at all:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585715/javascript-is-object-prototype-tostring-call-fully-reliable

Should I cast a vote to close it? Or should I delete it?

Comment: Well, it has been a while - did you come up with an answer to it on your own? One option would be answering it yourself (if you can).

Answer (score 6):

Just leave it be. You don't need to *close* it, as it is not off-topic, or too broad, or unclear, or primarily opinion based.

Either your question is hard to answer, or requires specialised knowledge and people with that knowledge just haven't found your question.

If, after a year, it still sits at 0 with low views, the [system will delete it for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). Until such time, it is not doing any harm.

If you care enough about getting an answer to that question, you can always put a bounty on it to attract attention to it.

Comment: Ok cool, I didn't know of this self-cleaning system, and I know it's not off-topic or a garbage question. I'll leave it alone then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Closing/deleting questions just because they didn't receive enough attentions/votes is not a good idea. If your question fits as per site's FAQ, it has enough information then closing/deleting is not an appropriate action. In fact such questions may be hard to answer. So instead of closing, start a bounty so it get more attentions.